# How do I find a user and the security group they belong to in active directory with their username and password in C#?

Tags: c#, security, active-directory

I'm trying to get a user out of Active directory using their username and password. Does anyone know how to do this in C# in addition to getting the security group they belong to?

Edit: This problem got more complicated (the requirements changed on me after a meeting). The security groups are nested within AD.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the DirectoryEntry class.

Here is a sample:

```
Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry
dirEntry = New DirectoryEntry("your LDAP info", "administrator", "password")

Dim entries As DirectoryEntries = dirEntry.Children
'' // Set login name and full name. 
Dim newUser As DirectoryEntry = entries.Add("CN=JONNY BOY", "User")

newUser.Properties("sAMAccountName").Add("jboy")
newUser.CommitChanges()
newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", "hi2343145gfdtgwdt")
Dim flags As Integer

flags = CInt(newUser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value)

'' //enable user below
newUser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = flags And Not &H2

'' //disable user below
newUser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = flags Or &H1


'' //lockout property
Dim l As Long
l = CType(newUser.Properties("lockoutTime").Value, Long)

If l <> 0 Then
    '' //account is locked out

    '' //so how do we unlock it?
    '' //we unlock it by setting it to 0
    newUser.Properties("lockoutTime").Value = 0
Else
    '' //account is 0 it is NOT locked out

End If

newUser.CommitChanges()

Dim j As DirectoryEntry = entries.Find("CN=JONNY BOY", "User")
j.Properties("mail").Value = "jon@yahoo.com"
j.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Finding what Groups/Distribution lists a specific user belongs to in active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506833/finding-what-groups-distribution-lists-a-specific-user-belongs-to-in-active-direc/1506857#1506857). Main point is related to `tokenGroups` property. BTW, you don't need to get with user password, just it's username.